# Which Stack Exchange site do I use to ask about affiliate questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know about affiliates for various things, like casinos and gambling affilates. I don't want to refer people to gamble of course, that would be pretty scummy. However using advanced coding I want to inject my affiliate code into the URL so that I can benefit from people who are already going to be gambling anyway.

So where would I post this?

P.S.: the question would be "What are the best gambling or casino affiliate programs?" or something to that extent.

Comment: Is it a code question? It is really unclear what you want to ask about.

Comment: no, it is about which affiliate site to use.

Comment: You're out of luck there; "what are the best xyz"-type questions are pretty much off topic all over the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: What @Mat said. Stack Exchange sites are not suitable for this kind of question (which x to use).

Comment: None of them. None of them, at all.

Comment: I don't think deleting this question makes sense. It's a valid question, despite the surprisingly large number of downvotes it got. Our Q&A model just doesn't quite work for support questions like this...

Comment: yea i know, there's no reason for all these downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

You won't find a site on the Stack Exchange network that takes that type of question.

Some have a tolerance for well-framed, detailed requests for help finding specific resources, but generally, "What's the best Foobar?" will be closed.

[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) will give you the rationale for this, and possible ways to turn that sort of question into a more constructive (for Stack Exchange) question.

Pro Webmasters has a few [questions tagged *affiliate*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affiliate), but you'll see that rule applied pretty clearly. Questions asking for recommendations on affiliate programs get closed. So while that site might be a place to go if you're, for instance, having trouble setting you your the whole thing, or simply testing the setup, it's not where you should go for general "what affiliate should I choose"-type questions.

Use a search engine to find candidates. Use forums and appropriate chat rooms to get feedback/recommendations for others.